# Recursive Prolog Fibonacci formula produces wrong result

Tags: recursion, prolog, fibonacci

Why does fib(2,1) return false for these lines of Prolog code?

```
fib(1,F) :-
    F is 1.
fib(N,F) :-
    N > 1,
    fib((N-1),F1),
    F is F1.
```

Comment: Have a look at the second clause, if you unify N=2 and F=1, then the first literal becomes 2-1.  But 2-1 > 1 does not hold.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `(N-1)` is a wrong mode to pass `1` when `N` is `2`.
You should do something like

```
fib(N,F) :-
  N > 1,
  NM1 is N-1,
  fib(NM1,F).
```

Second: your algorithm should unify `F` with `1` for every `N`. The [Fibonacci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) formula is really different; is more like

```
fib(0, 0).
fib(1, 1).
fib(N, F) :-
  N > 1,
  NM1 is N-1,
  NM2 is N-2,
  fib(NM1, FM1),
  fib(NM2, FM2),
  F is FM1+FM2.
```

Third: to avoid the problem of the exponential explosion of recursive calls, I suggest a different mode to compute Fibonacci

```
fibH(0, 0, 0).
fibH(1, 1, 0).
fibH(N, F, FM1) :-
  N > 1,
  NM1 is N-1,
  fibH(NM1, FM1, FM2),
  F is FM1+FM2.
fib(N, F) :-
  fibH(N, F, _).
```

Answer (score 0):

if your Prolog has tabling and big integers,

```
:- table fib/2.

fib(1, 1).
fib(2, 1).
fib(N, F) :-
  N > 2,
  N1 is N-1,  fib(N1, F1),
  N2 is N-2,  fib(N2, F2),
  F is F1+F2.
```

just remove the table/1 directive to see the exponential execution time grow...